# Best way to handle many incoming packets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm currently developing a simple P2P network as an exercise. Each node in the network sends heartbeats to a subset of the other nodes to be able to detect nodes that have left the network. Beside the heartbeat packets I send packets when new nodes join/leave the network, when they want to locate a resource (small text files), etc. All packets are UDP packets.

Whenever I receive a packet I start a new thread that handles that specific packet. I am however concerned with the amount of threads I start during one applications lifetime which adds up to quite a lot (Especially because of the heartbeats).  (There is also the risk of deadlocks and the like I would like to avoid).

I thought about having a queue or something where I put all incoming packets and have a single thread handling all packets one at a time from that queue (something like the producer-consumer pattern). I would like the packets to be handled rapidly so the sender doesn't think the packet is lost.

What is the best way to handle a lot of different incoming packets without having to start a new thread for each of them? Should I go with what I have, the producer-consuming or something different?

Comment: Sure. Use the producer-consumer with a LinkedList. Easiest way i can think of.

Comment: You may start with something old-fashioned like a way you mentioned yourself, do some benchmarks and then try something latest, like "Disruptor" (http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/) and then do some more benchmarks.

Comment: It might help to quantify "a lot of different incoming packets"... Relatively speaking, heartbeats shouldn't be much, when a modern system can typically handle hundreds to thousands of packets per second depending on the number and type of your NICs. I suspect heartbeats might be more in the dozens per minute range...

Comment: `java.nio.Selector` might do what you need.

Comment: @twalberg You are right about the heartbeats ;). Right now I send ~30 heartbeats per minute. When all other messages are sent depends on the users actions (leave, locate, join), but when I'm testing right now i'm not above 50-60 packets per minute all in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long does it take to your application to process one packet?

For the ping ones it is probably faster to just process them as they are received, you can put the others in a shared data structure such as a particular blocking queue, so when the queue is empty the worker threads wait for new jobs, and when a new jobs is added, a thread is awaken and will do the job.

Probably starting one thread per packet makes you consume more time on starting and stopping the threads than in actually doing the job.

If the things to do in response of a packet aren't so time consuming for all the type of packets, it might be the case that the extra time spent with the locks of the queue and scheduling threads makes your program slower rather than faster.

In any case use thread pool and start the workers in the beginning. If you want you could increase or reduce the number of working threads dynamically depending on the load of the past minutes.

Comment: The time varies slightly. Most packets are handled quickly but some actions involve new packets being sent and expecting a response. But I think I will go with the thread pool and queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `event driven architecture`. Creating a new thread for every packet is not scalable, so this will work to a certain amount of workload, but there is a point it won't work anymore. You could compare that to e.g. a chat program like the Facebook chat where messages are the packets.
An event driven architecture would be scalable and IMHO exactly what your looking for. Just do some googling, there libraries for many programming languages, so just pick the right one for you (I like to do that in Erlang, Scala, C or Python).

edit: ok, didn't see the java tag. But the language does not matter.

Take a look at this link for example:
http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html

I find it a quite good one to get the idea of event driven programming.

Comment: But he's using UDP, so he probably has only one file descriptor.

Comment: That does not exclude the possibility to make it asynchronous. Look for non-blocking sockets, asynchronous i/o or even event driven sockets (basically describes all the same idea).

Comment: I know it is still possible to do it, but i am not sure it is worth the hassle in this specific situation.